# Handler not yet determined error

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I don’t know anything about deploying a website, so I probably made some stupid mistake.

Anyways, I opened IIS 7 manager, created new virtual directory ( via Add Application ) and pointed it to physical directory where Visual studio saved my Web project. But when I tried to request an .aspx page, browser reported the following error (I won’t post the whole error, but just the interesting bits):

> Handler: Not yet determined 
>   Config Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions 
>   Logon User: Not yet determined

A) why is handler not yet determined? As far as I know, IIS7 does have Asp.Net handler registered?!

B) Why wouldn’t IIS have sufficient permissions? Does that mean I should give IIS higher privileges? Or does Asp.Net runtime have insufficient permissions?

C) Could the error also be due to the fact that perhaps it expected the user to authenticate itself? I’m assuming this due to *Logon user* not yet being determined?

D) And finally, any ideas how to make it work?

thanx

Answer (score 3):

> error code:0x8007000d

I started playing with permissions and all the stuff about access issues to web.config or applicationhost.config anyway those did not change the error.

while I was playing with my web.config I deleted rewrite tags from my config file and error changed. then I installed "web platform installer" and installed url rewrite module for IIS and played with some configuration now my site is working. it took about one day to find out this issue I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Does the identity of your IIS application pool have sufficient rights to access the folder that is hosting your site?