# Error Viewing ASP.NET applications After Installing IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7.5

I get the following error when I try to access a asp.net application on my local machine. Anyone have any ideas?

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>   The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
>
> Module    IIS Web Core
>   Notification    BeginRequest
>   Handler Not yet determined
>   Error Code  0x80070021
>   Config Error    This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
>   Config File \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TravelProduct\web.config
>   Requested URL   http://localhost:80/TravelProduct/CreateNewQuote.aspx
>   Physical Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TravelProduct\CreateNewQuote.aspx
>   Logon Method    Not yet determined
>   Logon User  Not yet determined

Comment: the application works fine, if I preview it from Visual Web Developer 2008

Comment: This looks like you have a broken web.config, can you post (minus anything sensitive)?

Answer (score 0):

please check if you deployed your application properly : [Deploying an ASP.NET Server (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731252(WS.10).aspx)

Comment: make sure ASP.NET feature is turned on/installed.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your web.config file, you must have added some configuration setting which is trying to overwrite the applicationHost.config settings.

Regards,
Vivek.

Answer (score 0):

check out my answer at [Handler not yet determined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766430/handler-not-yet-determined-error)

I did not realize url rewrite was not installed at the first time :)

Answer (score -1):

Reinstall your server asp.net for iss using this command:

> X:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v(.NET
>   Version)\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

This may solve your problem